# Rails partial need to be rendered twice with different content, but output is equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, random, partial

I have to output 2 blocks on the same page, each one of them must contain 3 random posts from database.

I have simple model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :random, -> { order('RANDOM()') }
end
```

I put the ActiveRecord code in **application_helper.rb**:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def random_posts(num = 3)
    posts = Post.uncached do
      Post.random.limit(num)
    end
  end
end
```

then in layout I use this call twice (**Slim template engine used**)

`= render random_posts`

which uses this partial **app/views/posts/_post.html.slim**

`a.btn = post.title`

Blocks are filled with 3 random posts from database, but they are the same in each blocks! Why is it so? Each block has to contain different posts.

I've created a [repo here](https://github.com/yakimoff/random_posts) with simple demonstration

Comment: What does your Post.random method look like?

Comment: I added model code to the question text. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give the long-hand syntax for render a try?  `= render partial: "post", collection: random_posts, as: :post`

Comment: @steakchaser just tried it, no luck. still the same

Comment: Just to provide a bit more information: after playing around with your repo, it seems the phenomenon is only occurring while rendering the view. It works just fine in the rails console. I cannot tell you why, at the moment though...

Comment: I don't think AR would cache this, maybe it's the helper.  Can you try without the helper?  `= render partial: "post", collection: Post.random.limit(3), as: :post`

Comment: @steakchaser just tried and still the same...

Comment: @Teeg thanks! still trying to figure it out. I want to have multiple blocks with random posts, but don't want to create a bunch of variables in my controller (block1_random_posts, block2_random_posts etc - depending on number of blocks in layout)

Comment: @user3333660, thanks for sharing a repo with your question! Wish more people would do that. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by flipping `uncached` to `cache`. I was experimenting on the `Post` model, but you could probably drop this in your helper just as easily:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.random_posts(n = 3)
    cache do
      random.limit(n)
    end
  end
end
```

For two calls of the method using `uncached`, the ActiveRecord log lines are `Post Load ...` and `CACHE ...`, but using `cache`, they are both `Post Load...`. I really wish I could explain why this works, but it's completely counterintuitive and makes no sense to me.

Comment: I can confirm this works in both the view and the rails console. What a fantastically odd thing.

Comment: @Zach Kemp Yay, it works! I just changed **uncached** to **cache** in helper as you mentioned! Thanks so much!

Comment: @user3333660 That's alright, welcome to SO. Accepting an answer is both a "thank you", and it lets other people know that "this post best answered my question / helped me the most", which of course is very helpful to the community in general. Best of luck in your endeavours!

Answer (score 0):

Forking your code, it seems that the collection `Post.random` is being cached in Rails in some way. If you add a debugger on the `random_posts` in `ApplicationHelper`:

```
Post.random.map(&:id)
```

Will have the same collection every time.

Taken from this [blogpost](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/rails-quick-tips-random-records), you could use this as an alternative:

In `ApplicationHelper.rb`:

```
def self.random_posts(num = 3)
  ids = Post.pluck(:id).shuffle[0..4]
  Post.where(id: ids)
end
```